# How to authenticate in django app via C#?

Tags: c#, python, django

I have a python script:

```
import requests

main_page_request = requests.get("http://carkit.kg/")
csrf_cookie = main_page_request.cookies.get("csrftoken", "")

r = requests.post("http://carkit.kg/", data={u'username': u'admin', u'password': u'admin', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_cookie }, cookies={'csrftoken': csrf_cookie})
print r.url
```

carkit.kg/ - is a login url in django app. Script prints one url if authentication succeed and another in other case. I tried to rewrite this script in C# (Unity3D game):

```
//get token
string url = "http://carkit.kg";
HttpWebRequest tokenRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
tokenRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebResponse tokenResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tokenRequest.GetResponse();
String token = tokenResponse.Cookies["csrftoken"].ToString().Split('=')[1];

//login 
HttpWebRequest loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
loginRequest.Method = "POST";
loginRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

loginRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("csrftoken", token, "/", "carkit.kg"));
String postData = "username=" + tempEmail;
postData += "&password=" + tempPass;
postData += "&csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + token;
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
loginRequest.ContentLength = data.Length + 1;
Debug.Log(data.Length);
    loginRequest.Timeout = 3000;

    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(tempEmail + ":" + tempPass));
    loginRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

loginRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
loginRequest.PreAuthenticate=true;

HttpWebResponse authResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loginRequest.GetResponse();
```

But I'm getting error 411 or timed out request. How to get the same result in C# code as in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setted [django rest api url](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) as simple post request destination and django returned token in data.